# Trying to run a for loop and it won't run at all

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to run this for loop and it appears that everything is properly formatted. Can someone explain what I am missing?

```
    axios.get(URL, HEADERS)
      .then((response) => {
        let day = new Date();
        let weatherData = response.data;
        let weathers = this.state.weatherInfo;
        // console.log(weatherData);
        let weather = [];

        for (let i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
          let currentTemperature = weatherData["daily"][i]["temp"]["day"];
          let currentWeather =
            weatherData["daily"][i]["weather"][i]["description"];
          let mainWeather = weatherData["daily"][i]["weather"][i]["main"];
          console.log(currentWeather);
          weather.push({
            temperature: currentTemperature,
            weather: currentWeather,
            main: mainWeather,
          });
        }
        console.log(weathers.length);
        console.log(weathers);
        this.setState({ weatherInfo: weather });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
```

Comment: is the `get` being run?

Comment: @KevinWang it is

Comment: @KevinWang even when i console log the current temperature for specific using for example 0 I get the correct value...

Comment: so the `console.log(weatherData);` that's commented-out is being run, but `console.log(currentWeather);` is not run?  and is `console.log(error);` being ran?

Comment: @KevinWang console.log(weatherData) and console.log(currentWeather) is being run. console.log(error) has not ran..

Comment: Based on your conversation here, it seems you are getting the right data you need from the axios request. Although, I would suggest you use something like optional chaining when going that deep into object responses. Anyway I assume the problem is on your setState(I might be wrong)....you might need to bind `this` as `this.setState` in the current position might be pointing to another `this` within resolved request

Comment: @kvothe, you are telling that for loop won't run at all but console.log(currentWeather) is being run which is under for loop. how?